# Remove 2D points where nearest neighbor exceeds certain distance

Tags: list-manipulation, distance, nearest

I have the following 2D points:

```
coords = 
  {{68.5909, 102.136}, {10.6, 101.3}, {103.5, 99.4091}, {49.5, 96.5}, 
   {87.3182, 94.3182}, {28.8636, 87.4091}, {66.5, 84.}, {100.333, 78.5}, 
   {48.5, 77.}, {82.1923, 76.4231}, {11.4167, 76.1667}, {29.5909, 68.1364}, 
   {65., 64.}, {102., 61.7857}, {84.5, 60.3}, {47.5, 58.3}, {11.5, 54.}, 
   {29.8846, 49.9615}, {75.5, 46.}, {94.5, 46.}, {111., 47.}, {58.5, 44.3}, 
   {2.31818, 39.0455}, {42., 38.6}, {20.5909, 34.1364}, {105.25, 31.9167}, 
   {87.2143, 31.3571}, {70.5, 29.7}, {53.3182, 26.3182}, {34.5, 22.3}, 
   {13.5, 19.5}, {97.8636, 17.1364}, {80.7, 15.5}, {64.4, 12.8}, {46.5, 10.3}, 
   {26.5, 7.7}, {6.16667, 4.38889}, {108.5, 3.7}, {92.5, 2.3}, {23., 0.5}, {75.5, 0.5}}
```

The sorted distances between next nearest neighbors are:

```
distances = Sort[EdgeList@NearestNeighborGraph[coords, 1] /. 
            UndirectedEdge -> EuclideanDistance, Greater]

{22.946, 19.8693, 19.5256, 19.2864, 18.7267, 18.4049, 18.2565,
18.1772, 17.8045, 17.5483, 17.4258, 17.0848, 16.9706, 16.9637,
16.8964, 16.7972, 16.7965, 16.7962, 16.7016, 16.6481, 16.6092,
16.5221, 16.3553, 16.2874, 16.2636, 16.1422, 16.0611, 15.8758,
15.7761, 8.00562}
```

How can I remove all 2d data points from the list `coords` of which the next neighbor distance is greater than the mean distance (`Mean[distances] = 17.1175`)?

```
Show[ListPlot[coords], NearestNeighborGraph[coords, 1], 
 AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
f = Nearest[coords]
m = Mean[EuclideanDistance[#, Last@f[#, 2]] & /@ coords]
s = Select[f[#, {2, m}] & /@ coords, Length@# == 2 &]

ListPlot[{coords, Flatten[s, 1]}, 
         PlotStyle -> Directive /@ {{PointSize[Large], Red}, Green}, 
         Epilog -> Line /@ s]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: That is excellent ...

Comment: I'm confuse the `Nearest` will result to a different mean distance.

Comment: Ok,I find out the `NearestNeighborGraph[coords,1,DirectedEdges->True]` will get a same result with you.

Comment: Do you see the same (yodes last plot) that in your code when the mean is calculated some distance are added twice. How would the solution for your code look like, when the distance between two points which are nearest to each other should only be counted once?

Comment: @mrz The logic behind the "distances counted twice" looks right to me. What we are doing is the following: "Take one point. Sum up the distance to its nearest neighbor. At the end divide by the number of points". Sometimes point A is the nearest neighbor of point B, and point B is the nearest neighbor of point A, so that distance appears twice in the sum, but it looks OK to me. If you want another "logic" for calculating the mean distance please specify it.

Answer (score 4):

```
nng = EdgeList@NearestNeighborGraph[coords, 1]
m = Mean[EuclideanDistance @@@ nng]
p = Pick[nng, EuclideanDistance @@ # < m & /@ nng]
Graph[p, VertexCoordinates -> VertexList[Graph@p], Axes -> True, 
 VertexSize -> 0.2, VertexStyle -> Red]
```

[image]

and for completeness:

```
d = Thread[p -> EuclideanDistance @@@ p];
Graph[p, VertexCoordinates -> VertexList[Graph@p], Axes -> True, 
 VertexSize -> 0.2, VertexStyle -> Red, EdgeLabels -> d]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
edgelist = List @@@ EdgeList@NearestNeighborGraph[coords, 1];
meanDistance = EuclideanDistance @@@ edgelist // Mean;
pair = If[EuclideanDistance @@ # < meanDistance, #, Nothing] & /@ 
  edgelist
```

> {{{103.5, 99.4091}, {87.3182, 94.3182}}, {{100.333, 78.5}, {102., 
>      61.7857}}, {{82.1923, 76.4231}, {84.5, 60.3}}, {{84.5, 
>      60.3}, {75.5, 46.}}, {{29.8846, 49.9615}, {42., 38.6}}, {{75.5, 
>      46.}, {58.5, 44.3}}, {{94.5, 46.}, {87.2143, 31.3571}}, {{111., 
>      47.}, {105.25, 31.9167}}, {{42., 38.6}, {53.3182, 
>      26.3182}}, {{20.5909, 34.1364}, {13.5, 19.5}}, {{87.2143, 
>      31.3571}, {70.5, 29.7}}, {{34.5, 22.3}, {46.5, 10.3}}, {{34.5, 
>      22.3}, {26.5, 7.7}}, {{13.5, 19.5}, {6.16667, 4.38889}}, {{97.8636,
>       17.1364}, {92.5, 2.3}}, {{80.7, 15.5}, {64.4, 12.8}}, {{80.7, 
>      15.5}, {75.5, 0.5}}, {{26.5, 7.7}, {23., 0.5}}, {{108.5, 
>      3.7}, {92.5, 2.3}}}

Then let's visulize it.

```
Graphics[{PointSize[0.02], Point[coords], Red, Line[pair], Blue, 
  Text[EuclideanDistance @@ #, Mean@#] & /@ pair}, 
 PlotLabel -> StringForm["The Mean Distance is ``", meanDistance], 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Red, 18]]
```

[image]

---

**Update:**

The update just wanna alert the OP to noted your `distances` will lead to a difference result.As the vulgar  understanding,I think the currently accepted answer is more reasonable.But in any case it's up to what you want.When we use the `UndirectedEdge` in default.It just count one time when two point is nearest each other.The graph is like following.

```
NearestNeighborGraph[coords, 1, VertexSize -> Large]
```

[image]

But when you use `DirectedEdge` to count it,it will count two times in every pair

```
NearestNeighborGraph[coords, 1, VertexSize -> Large, 
 DirectedEdges -> True, 
 EdgeShapeFunction -> GraphElementData["Arrow", "ArrowSize" -> .02]]
```

[image]

This is the reason there are some differences in our answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your investigation  ... I was not aware of it. In the last plot I only want that each distance should be counted once ... to determine the mean next neighbor distance.